# Consistency of One-Pion Exchange with Selection Rules for NN Pion Production (in Chiral EFT, e.g.)

Tags: angular-momentum, nuclear-physics, parity, effective-field-theory, pions

Hope you're ready for a long question, but I think quite an interesting one!

One-pion exchange is an established nucleon-nucleon potential which is well-defined for any joint angular momentum state of the two nucleons. A full derivation may be found for example [here](https://archive.int.washington.edu/users/mjs5/Class_560/lec560_3/node2.html), but the essential idea is that one combines two copies of the leading-order $\pi NN$ vertex $-\frac{g_A}{2 f_\pi} N^\dagger \tau^a \sigma \cdot \nabla \pi^a N$ with a pion propagator. From here one can derive potentials as a function of the pion momentum, and project them to relevant nuclear partial waves such as $^1S_0$.

Simultaneously, production of both p-wave and s-wave pions from $NN$ pairs is well-studied from a chiral EFT perspective. In the literature, for instance [Malafaia's thesis (pp. 101-103)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/nucl-th/0602026.pdf), it is made clear that not all possible spin-isospin-angular momentum production channels are permitted. In particular for proton-proton scattering, where isospin cannot change ($\Delta T = 0$), antisymmetry of the nucleon states combined with parity conservation at the production vertex together imply the following relation:

$$(-1)^{(\Delta S)} = \pi_\pi (-1)^{l_\pi}$$

where $\pi_\pi$ is the intrinsic parity of the pion (negative), and $l_\pi$ is its angular momentum with respect to the outgoing $NN$ system. The usual Fermi relation $-1 = (-1)^{S+T+L}$ holds as well. The resultant permitted processes are shown in Table 5.4 of the same thesis, but the key point is that only two transitions involving $^1S_0$ are permitted, and both involve an s-wave pion:

$$ ^1S_0 \rightarrow (^3P_0)s \quad and \quad ^3P_0 \rightarrow (^1S_0)s$$

With regards to one-pion exchange, this doesn't at first seem like a problem. The $^1S_0$ state would simply become a $^3P_0$ state while the $\pi NN$ intermediate state persists, and then return to a $^1S_0$ state after reabsorption. However, there is in fact a major problem.

The chiral EFT lagrangian vertex mentioned, $-\frac{g_A}{2 f_\pi} N^\dagger \tau^a \sigma \cdot \nabla \pi^a N$, can only be responsible for p-wave pion emission, since only in the p-wave does the pion wavefunction have a derivative at the origin. The NLO term in chiral EFT is s-wave ($\propto N^\dagger \tau_a \dot{\pi}^a \sigma \cdot \nabla N$), but is suppressed by a further $\frac{1}{2 m_N}$.

After that long explanation, essentially my question is: how can both of these details be true at the same time? I have a few suspicions, but for each of them have a reason to be skeptical:

- Perhaps because the pion in one-pion exchange never emerges as an external state, some of the conservation laws used to derive the selection rules can be broken?  Of course this can be true for very short-lived states which do not conserve energy, but I am skeptical because parity and angular momentum are such discrete quantities for these nuclear states.
- Perhaps I am misunderstanding the need to define a true pion-nucleon intermediate state in one-pion exchange, when one could think of the virtual pion as being exchanged instantaneously. For context, I am thinking about it this way because I want to insert some other operators between the intermediate nucleon and pion fields while the virtual pion is "in transit" -- but even if this were not the case, it seems like the two formulations should be consistent.
- Perhaps I simply need to go to a higher order in the selection rules, and eventually find an angular momentum NN state $X$ such that $^1S_0 \rightarrow X p$ is permitted. At a first glance $^1D_2$ seems to do the trick, but I am skeptical that a process as simple as one-pion exchange would truly need to put the NN system in such a high angular momentum state if only briefly. I suppose this is the leading contender, but I would appreciate any thoughts or ideas.

Thanks for reading this far! :)